# Intersects query crashes SQL Server service

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I'm at a bit of a loss on an intersects query that I'm sending via EF6. It works great against my test and production databases, but I recently set up a new box and restored my production database onto the local machine and the intersects query hard crashes the SQL Server process. Overview of the line of code that blows this up:

```
public async Task<TicketResultModel[]> ResultsByBoundingBox(DbGeography box)
{
    var addressIds = await _addresses.Where(a => a.LatLon.Intersects(box)).Select(a => a.Id).ToArrayAsync();
        ...
}
```

So, my question is what should I check that would make this particular query succeed against my other databases, but fail against the local SQL Server 2012 installation? Mind you, everything else seems to work.

I have already installed the `SQLSysClrTypes`. Is there something else (there must be!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue of x86 vs x64. Rather than giving any sort of error message at all about wrong architecture, the process would just crash. Hard. I had x86 SQL Server 2012 installed. The machine architecture is x64, so I think the box was magically choosing to use the x64 spatial libraries. Unfortunately, this magic did not result in unicorns and rainbows: That happened after uninstalling SQL Server 2012 x86 and installing SQL Server 2014 x64.

Hope this helps someone who has done something silly!